# Pinch gesture one finger ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i have successfully added the pinch gesture on my UILabel, and i can increase and decrease the size.
The UILabel has also a pan and rotate gesture recognizers and are both working, but i want the pinch gesture to work not only if both fingers are in the object, but also if just one finger is on object and the other is outside (in case the object is too small to be pressed with 2 fingers).
If i try to do that it triggers the pan gesture and not the pinch.

Here is my function that set the recognizers to my UILabel:

```
func setGestures(object: UIView){
        // recognizer for the dragging move
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasDragged(gesture:)))
        let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasRotated(gesture:)))
        var pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasPinched(gesture:)))

        // set gestures for the text label
        object.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        object.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        object.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
        object.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        object.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
 }
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the pinch gesture recognizer to the UIView's superview. If you have more than one view that must react to a pinch, you will need to determine which two views the fingers are in and decide which view will get changed.